# Specify custom docker socket address when using k3d?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, k3d

I have just started using k3d for local testing of ephemeral clusters. Locally it works great - I use pretty much default docker settings with no problems.

I would like to add automated tests like this using GitLab CI. On GitLab workers, the docker is not available on the default Unix domain socket: `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, but rather a TCP socket, i.e.: `tcp://docker:2376`. This means, for the tests to work, I would need to somehow tell k3d to use the custom address.

I could not find anywhere in the k3d docs info how to use a different than default docker address. Is there some configuration entry that could be used?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `DOCKER_HOST` variable, which is respected by all Docker commandline tools as well as k3d.

Eg:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
k3d cluster list
docker ps
```